# Representations in Archimedean quadratic modules

Tags: mathematical-software, semidefinite-programming, real-algebra, semialgebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb R [X] = \mathbb R [X_1,\dots,X_n]$ and $\Sigma[X] = \big\{ \, f \in \mathbb R[X] \mid \exists r \in \mathbb N, \ g_i \in \mathbb R[X] \colon f = g_1^2 + \dots + g_r^2   \,\big\}$ denote the Sum of Squares polynomials. $M \subset \mathbb R [X]$ is a quadratic module if $1\in M$, $\Sigma [X]\cdot M\subset M$ and $M+M\subset M$.

Let $M \subset \mathbb R [X_1, X_2]$ be the quadratic module generated by $X_1$, $X_2$ and $1-X_1-X_2$. The associated semialgebraic set is $S= \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 \mid x \ge 0, \ y\ge 0, \ 1-x-y \ge 0 \}$, which is compact. Since $M$ is generated by linear polynomials then $M$ is also Archimedean (Prestel Delzell, Positive Polynomials, Cor. 6.3.5).

Consider the polynomial $f = X_1 X_2 + 1$. Since $f > 0$ on $S$, then $f \in M$ by [Putinar Positivstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positivstellensatz#Putinar's_Positivstellensatz), i.e. $f = s_0 + s_1 X_1 + s_2 X_2 + s_3 (1 - X_1 - X_2)$ for some $s_i \in \Sigma [X]$.

I am interested in finding the explicit Sum of Squares coefficients in such a representation. It is well know that this is a semidefinite programming problem, but I could not find an easy access tool/software/library to compute explicitly the representation.

Then I am asking for references to this kind of software, and/or to explicit expressions for $s_0$, $s_1$, $s_2$ and $s_3$.

More generally, I am interested in the SoS coefficients in the representation $\prod X_i + 1 \in M(X_1,\dots, X_n, 1- \sum X_i)$.

Comment: It seems that this problem has been investigated recently in the literature. See [this paper](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~vicki/preprint/PsdSosSurvey.pdf), section 3